# How to enable power failure notification?

Tags: power-management, notification

I need to enable power (AC) failure (off-line) and power on (on-line) notifications, like this notification:

[image: Enter image description here![]

I searched and tried to do that, but I didn't find any successful articles. I use these commands to monitor my AC adapter:

```
acpi- a

echo ac_adapter=$(acpi -a | cut -d' ' -f3 | cut -d- -f1)
```

But I don't know how to write notification on code.

Can I write a shell script like the following?

```
#!/bin/bash

power=ac_adapter=$(acpi -a | cut -d' ' -f3 | cut -d- -f1)
s1="$power"


if [ "$s1" = "off-line" ]; then

    notify-send  --urgency=low "Power Manager" "Power Down" -i battery_low
    echo "notification: off" >~/.scripts/notification

else
  if [ $s1 = "on-line" ]; then
    notify-send  --urgency=normal "Power Manager" "Power Up" -i battery_full

  fi
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell script below works for AC power updates like plugged in and plugged out. You should run this code at start-up; it runs in an infinite loop.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

old="$(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC | fgrep online | awk '{print $2}')"
while sleep 1; do
    new="$(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC | fgrep online | awk '{print $2}')"
    if [ "$new" != "$old" ]; then
        if [ "$new" == "yes" ]; then
            notify-send --icon=gnome-power-manager "AC power on"
        elif [ "$new" == "no" ]; then
            notify-send --icon=gnome-power-manager "Battery power on"
        fi
    fi
    old="$new"
done
```

Edit the `notify-send` as you wish.

Comment: `./script.sh: line 5: [: ==: unary operator expected`
`./script.sh: line 7: [: ==: unary operator expected`
And i made some changes `if [ "$stat" == 'yes' ]
elif [ "$stat" == 'no' ]` Is it correct

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: i ran this code in terminal but out put is empty, `echo $(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ACAD | grep online | awk '{ print $2}')` Any idea Sir?

Comment: can you post your <upower -d> output

Comment: `Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               Samsung SDI
  model:                DELL JXFRP1C
  serial:               9489
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Fri 11 Jul 2014 09:51:37 PM IST (825 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes`

Comment: `Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC
  native-path:          AC
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Fri 11 Jul 2014 09:51:15 PM IST (847 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    online:             yes`

Comment: k wait i am updating the code

Comment: i updated the shell script now.

Comment: Is it working now.

Comment: yes, It's working, Thank you very much sir. Great help. Thank you again.

Comment: I use this `--expire-time=5` But notification never expire, how do i add `--expire-time=` option to time out.

Comment: you can use <upower -e> to view objects path for your power devices and then <upower -i> to view information regarding them. For more see upower --help

Comment: notify-send ignores the timeout command its a bug see it here http://askubuntu.com/questions/110969/notify-send-ignores-timeout

Comment: Oh. Thank you again for everything you've done sir. This is big favor.

Comment: Instead of that add line after notify-send to script to end notify send <sleep 3; killall "processname of notify-send">

Answer (score 0):

According to Sudheer's answer I wrote another shell script, and it works fine on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) with `notify-send -t` option. When I add `--expire-time=TIME` it won't work, but `notify-send -t 30` works perfectly. Why?

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

stat=$(acpi -a | cut -d' ' -f3 | cut -d- -f1)


if [ "$stat" == 'on' ];then
a=yes
elif [ "$stat" == 'off' ];then
a=no
fi

while true; do

    stat=$(acpi -a | cut -d' ' -f3 | cut -d- -f1)

    if [ "$stat" != "$a" ]; then
        if [ "$stat" == "on" ];then
            notify-send -t 30 --icon=gpm-ac-adapter "AC power on"
        elif [ "$stat" == "off" ];then
            notify-send -t 30 --icon=notification-power-disconnected "AC Power Off Battery power on"
        fi
    fi
    a=$stat
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Time parameter is not implemented in notify-send!....one of the most controversial bug...https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/notify-osd/+bug/390508