# Create instant desktop notification linux

Tags: notification, notify-send

I'm writing a program which notify user about something repeatedly with new message each time using `notify-send`, but the problem is I want notifications to stay there for 5 seconds but it should be removed or deleted whenever new notification is created from notify-send.

Answer (score 1):

`notify-send` does take a `-t` argument for time:

```
-t, --expire-time=TIME
Specifies the timeout in milliseconds at which to expire the notification.
```

But you're at the mercy of whatever handles the notifications as to whether or not that's implemented.

I tried it on KDE with `notify-send -t 5000 test` and the notification was on the screen for only three seconds. This *may* work in Ubuntu proper with `notify-osd` but it may not. If you want to be certain, you'll have to implement your own notification system.

Comment: I think this is still the case in Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/110969/notify-send-ignores-timeout I tried to set it without succes.

Comment: Thanks @JacobVlijm! That makes sense. I notice that [the bug report for this against `notify-osd` got a `wontfix`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/notify-osd/+bug/390508). It seems like a design decision to stop things hogging the screen excessively.

Comment: Seems to work on XFCE, `notify-send -t 10000` stays up for about 10 seconds, plus the "minimum" time of about 1.5 seconds. `-t 5` still stays for 1.5 seconds too.