# notify-send not working, seems many bugs

Tags: command-line, gnome, notification, notify-send

i'm trying to create notification script but it doesnt work. 
 When i click for example "control+alt+m" it should pop notification which it does, but its like default and i cant change anything.  
 I tried to use some of commands for notify-send but its just not working.  
 And one more huge problem is its not working in full screen like i'm in-game and i want to click "control+alt+m" and its not showing up.  
 I cant do anything, i tried to write -critical still not working. need help with notifications.

here is my script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
notify-send "Dota2 Heroes" -t 10000
```

P.S default is 5sec time, -t 10000 = 10sec but its not working, notification disappears in 5sec

Comment: The time-out of notify-send is unfortunately not arbitrary :( (by design) see the linked post, and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/notify-osd/+bug/390508

Comment: this work for me with 10 seconds `notify-send -t 10000 "title" "message"`

Comment: @bistoco sure, but try `-t 50000`, it'll still be 10 sec :) (on unity).

Comment: it works too, note that the order of params on @HeicPy example is wrong according to manual

Comment: @bistoco Are you on Unity? No matter the value, it stays 10 sec. here, as is documented for Unity.

Comment: No, xfce, the post says nothing about Unity.

Comment: HeicPy, are you using Unity? It is kind of essential to know :)

Comment: Make sure your shortcuts are "GLOBAL", ie, any program can have focus and they still trigger.

Comment: Especially look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/544787/344926) in the duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple:

> Ubuntu's Notify OSD and GNOME Shell both ignore this parameter.

Open the man page

```
man notify-send
```

and you can read this:

```
-t, --expire-time=TIME
      The duration, in milliseconds, for the notification to appear on
      screen. (Ubuntu's Notify OSD and GNOME Shell both ignore this
      parameter.)
```

Comment: I am afraid OP lost interest in his own question, he never replied to any of the comments... Didn't know it was even in the man pages though! (not in my version btw- Unity 14.04:        " -t, --expire-time=TIME
              Specifies  the  timeout in milliseconds at which to expire the
              notification.")

Comment: @JacobVlijm Oh, yes `Last seen Jul 15 at 21:57`

Comment: Good, but [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/544787/344926) is even better!  ;-)

Comment: so yeah, as i see there is no chance to create notification. Thanks for answears

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)