# How to create your own window gui like notification

Tags: gui, window, notification

I want to ask is there any chance to create your own notification window, you know when you click hotkey from your keyboard and you are in-game, it will pops out for example text. You guys have any idea?

Comment: Would something such as **libnotify** with `notify-send` work for you?

Comment: @earthmeLon that seems not working for OP: http://askubuntu.com/questions/648779/notify-send-not-working-seems-many-bugs#comment931288_648779

Comment: libnotify not working

Answer (score 1):

Use xmessage. Just run the following in a terminal emulator (Ctrl+Alt+T):

```
xmessage here_comes_your_message
```

A notification window will pop up.

Comment: its just message,  and you cant get this in-game or in full screen application

Comment: But what do you want? A script or something? Be more specific.

Comment: i want to use script for poping some information when you are in-game and it will automatically turn off like in 5sec then you can click hotkey again and you will see another message with another info you know

Comment: The code for that would not be that simple... You would have to use something instead of simple bash scripts.

Comment: RIP HOPE, i thought it will be nice with notify-send but sadly it is buged... GG thanks for answears anyway.