# Configure Unity notifications to close on click

Tags: unity, notification

I like those notification bubbles of Unity, but the one thing I really hate of them is that I can't click them away.

I know when I hover above them they become almost transparent and that I may click through them on the window below, but I would prefer a small **(x)** icon to be able to close it.

Alternatively, it might also close when clicking anywhere on it, that does not matter.

Is it possible to set this up on Ubuntu 15.04 with Unity Desktop? How would I do this?

Comment: Hi Byte Commander, posted my answer. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Sorry, I totally missed that you wrote one of your totally awesome scripts for me again! ;D

Comment: Definitely a duplicate of [Notify-send ignores timeout?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110969/notify-send-ignores-timeout).  The second answer is what you need and even give you more then you need...  **;-)**  (Sorry for having a better answer *for once* then one of your beautiful scripts @JacobVlijm)  **:P**

Comment: @Fabby I am a bit surprised you even can think of seeing this as a dupe. Both the question and the (goal of) the answer(s) are quite different. Am I missing something? This is totally not about ignoring time out, nor is the requested solution.

Comment: @JacobVlijm: Yes you're missing something: I have that repository installed and that's one of the things it allows you to do: hover over the message to keep it endlessly and click to make it go away *and many more goodies*... **;-)**

Comment: I see, but then still the fact that (part) of the answer suits the question does not make *the question* a dupe. See http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13964/dupe-but-no-dupe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Change the notification's mouse- over behaviour

*Almost* what you asked for, and possibly what you might like, a tiny, very light background script (no noticeable load to your system whatsoever, if no notification runs, it will only wait/check for one to appear) that will *change* the mouse-over effect of the notifications from fade:

[image]

[image]

to disappear (close):

[image]

This will only take effect if the mouse is moved *from outside the area into the notification area*, to make sure you won't miss the notifications if your mouse already is in the notification area if the message is launched.

#### How to use

1. The script needs `xdotool`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `manage_notifications.py`
3. Test-run the script by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/manage_notifications.py
   ```

   with the script running, open a terminal window and run the command:

   ```
   notify send 'This is a test'
   ```

   now move the mouse to the notification. Instead of fading, it should disappear.
4. If all works fine, add it to your startup applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add the command:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && python3 /path/to/manage_notifications.py"
   ```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

w = int([s.split("x")[0] for s in subprocess.check_output(
    ["xrandr"]).decode("utf-8").split() if "+0+0" in s][0]
        )

def get_mouse():
    loc = subprocess.check_output(["xdotool", "getmouselocation"]).decode("utf-8").split()[:2]
    return [int(n.split(":")[1]) for n in loc]

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    try: 
        subprocess.check_output(["pgrep", "notify-osd"]).decode("utf-8")
        curloc1 = get_mouse(); t = 1
        while t < 10:
            time.sleep(1)
            curloc2 = get_mouse()
            test1 = curloc1[0] > w - 400 and curloc1[1] < 400
            test2 = curloc2[0] > w - 400 and curloc2[1] < 400
            if all([test1 == False, test2 == True]):
                subprocess.Popen(["pkill", "notify-osd"])
                break
            curloc1 = curloc2
            t = t+1
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: And another great script =) +1

Comment: Do you have a GitHub repository for that?

Comment: @A.B. I do have one, but probably should maintain it better. I will get organized after summer :)

Comment: Works as a charm, although I would have preferred the notification to close on click instead of on mouseover, but I can live with that, I think. ;-)

Comment: `notify send 'This is a test'` didn't work for me. I had to use `notify-send 'This is a test'`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom.
2. Bind the command `xkill` to a keyboard shortcut (for instance I've set mine to <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> )
3. Whenever you see a notification, click the keyboard shortcut , hover the pointer over the notification, click it, and it goes away.

Comment: Wrong. `xkill`-ing a notification bubble kills the window behind it instead and leaves the bubble intact!

Comment: @ByteCommander Sorry, that was a bit of error on my side - I've installed xfce on my laptop with 15.04 before, and xfce replaces `notify-osd` with its own package `xfce4-notifyd`, popups from which are perfectly killable with `xkill`, but on pc with 14.04 I've same behavior as you described. I can suggest another alternative - bind `pkill notify-osd` to a keyboard shortcut and whenever you have a popup appear, hit the shortcut. Let me know if I should edit that into my answer

Comment: Yes, do the edit and I can remove my downvote. Give it a header that the above solution is XFCE only and it's at least a valid and correct answer. trying now whether the other suggestion works.

Comment: I tried it and it seems to work, but when there are multiple notifications in a queue, it removes all of them instead of just making the currently displayed one disappear. If you could think of a workaround to that, it would be great, but I'll at least give you an upvote as soon as the edit is done.